# Adding example value for a controller parameter in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, openapi, core-api

I have a .NET Core Web API that I have enabled XML comments on in the `program.cs` file by calling `IncludeXmlComments`.

[image]

I have the following XML comments set on my controller:
[image: XML Comments]

But the webpage displays an empty example column:

[image: display of no example]

How do I get the Example column to be populated by the example attribute inside the  tag?

The XML on my model does update when I change it so I believe this is correctly configured. I cannot get the Example column to hold a value for the controller parameter.